# Linux: per-application traffic monitoring (not nethogs)

Tags: linux, monitoring, network-traffic

Please note it's not duplicate of other questions where answer with `nethogs` is accepted, since `nethogs` isn't what I need.

I want to know how much each of my applications have eaten network traffic, on which interface, and when. `nethogs` displays realtime traffic only. But I want to have the statistics: how much traffic each application used, hourly/daily/monthly/etc.

On Windows there are many such utilities, and they work literally out-of-the-box, but on Linux I can't find any.

Is there some utility like that?

Comment: Perhaps expanding on the situation would help. Why do you need to monitor bandwidth per application ? Why do you need history ?

Comment: I would look into Cacti for this.  
You will need to build your own scripts to track which port is using how much data with a program like nethogs, and then store it with Cacti which will then allow you to generate graphs etc with the stored data

Comment: @Lawrence, when I'm on the limited traffic plan, it would be really useful to know which application eats much traffic.  History is even more useful, but if there is some utility that could store at least total bandwidth per application, I'd try it too, of course.

Comment: If you left nethogs open for the duration of the period you're online, you could probably get an idea...otherwise I can't think of anything that will do what you want out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

You can use nethog with total bandwidth monitored per MB since it started with:

`sudo nethogs -v 3`

[image]

---

you can use [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/iftop/) as an alternative too.